# Unable to get Google definitions to Standard Output

Tags: filter, stdout

I aim to filter my Google results right at terminal such that I get only Google's definitions.

I am trying to run the following in Mac's terminal

```
open http://www.google.com/search?q=define:cars&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8:en-GB:official&client=vim
```

A similar command for Firefox is

```
open http://www.google.com/search?q=define:cars&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a
```

**Which client can you use to have Google's html page to your standard output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"GET"

```
GET 'http://www.google.com/search?q=define:cars&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8:en-GB:official&client=vim'
```

See also "HEAD".

The command can be installable on Gnu/Linux OS:

```
[elcuco@pinky ~]$ rpm -qf `which GET`
perl-libwww-perl-5.808-2mdv2008.1
```

In theory you could also use "wget" and output to stdout using something like this:

```
wget http://www.google.com -O - --quiet
```

However I cannot get it to work with this example URL.

Comment: Do you know how to install Get in Mac?

Comment: According to "rpm -qi" it's a perl module, so it's "homepage" is CPAN. I wish I could help you more, but my experience with Mac is very low...

unless you want to buy me a Mac ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To use Google search not through their web interface, you're almost certainly better off using their [API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

However, I think `curl` is the right tool to use to download a web page if that's what you have to do (and it probably isn't)